# Confused about adding an existing file to Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: tfs

I am trying to add the file "DSTB_QB.xml" to an existing project in TFS.  I added the file to an existing project from Source Control Explorer using "Add Items to Folder", but I have to check it out separately from the rest of the project.  Additionally, although it appears in the "App_Data" folder (which is where I want it) in my local workspace, it does not appear under the "App_Data" folder in Solution Explorer. It is as if this file is under source control, but not part of the project.  How can I make the file part of the project?[image]

Comment: Add it to the project the same way you would any other file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not add just with Source Control Explorer because you Visual Studio Project does not know why some file exist on file system (maybe this temporary file). But if you add existing file with Solution Explorer to existing project this file will be added to source control automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by right-clicking on the "App_Data" folder in Solution Explorer and selecting "Add->Existing Item".  I'm not sure if that's what the above commenter meant, but it worked.

Now my question is: Why did I have to add the file in Source Control Explorer AND in Solution Explorer?  More specifically, why wasn't adding it in Source Control Explorer sufficient?